# SQL Server varchar(max) is not working properly

Tags: sql-server, max, varchar

In the following example, the txt column length is not correctly shown.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test
(
    Id int IDENTITY,
    txt varchar(max)
);

insert into test(txt) select REPLICATE('0',8000);
insert into test(txt) select REPLICATE('00',8000);

select id, len(txt) from test;

drop table test;
```

The result shown for both were 8000.

Could any body help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert something into a `varchar(max)` column - your inserting code needs to explicitly convert it to `varchar(max)` - try this:

```
insert into test(txt) select REPLICATE(cast('00' as varchar(max)), 8000);
```

That should give you a string of 16'000 characters length in the table.